# NodeJS Sequelize JSON Response for Ember data

Tags: json, node.js, ember.js, ember-data, sequelize.js

I am creating an API for an Ember-App (using ember-data) with NodeJS and Sequelize. I currently have the api returning:

```
{"customer":{"id":2,
 "username":"jdsnell",
 "policies":
  [{"id":5,"policytype":"Life","createdAt":null,"updatedAt":null},  
  {"id":6,"policytype":"Auto","createdAt":null,"updatedAt":null}]
 }}
```

Generated by the following code:

```
router.get('/:customer_id',function(req,res){
    models.customers.find({
        where:{
            id:req.params.customer_id
        },
        include: [models.policies]
    }).then(function(customers){        
        return res.json({customer:customers});
    });
})
```

I need the response to return only the id's which is what Ember data is expecting, such as:

```
{"customer":{"id":2,
 "username":"jdsnell",
 "policies":
  [5,6]
 }}
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js sequelize embed hasMany IDs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20017334/node-js-sequelize-embed-hasmany-ids)